# Upgrade beta OS on iPod Touch?

Tags: iphone, xcode

My iPod has the Beta OS 3.0 and I can't find any way to upgrade it to 3.1. ITunes says is up to date, XCode doesn't offer any upgrade options. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try booting it up in recovery mode? (shut off, and restart while holding the home button with itunes running). odds are it'll let you install it with a fresh version of whatever the latest os you have.

Comment: That did it. the normal restore nor upgrade were not working I guess because the existing OS was the 3.0 beta.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to download the latest iPhone SDK plus the OS 3.1 for the iPod touch in order to upgrade it to 3.1 from within Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, (it's been a while) I fixed this problem by just hitting the "restore" button in iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

Is 3.1 still in beta? I thought it was officially out.  In this case, if you have an Ipod touch, I think you have to pay for the upgrade.